# pip install pydoop issue

Tags: python, hadoop

When I install pydoop in Ubuntu 16.0.4, I get error as below:

```
~$ pip install pydoop
Collecting pydoop
  Using cached pydoop-1.2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    using setuptools version 27.2.0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-Q8VQGn/pydoop/setup.py", line 70, in <module>
        JVM_LIB_PATH, JVM_LIB_NAME = jvm.get_jvm_lib_path_and_name(JAVA_HOME)
      File "pydoop/utils/jvm.py", line 93, in get_jvm_lib_path_and_name
        return os.path.dirname(jvm_path), jvm_lib_name if jvm_path else None
      File "/home/hadoop/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 122, in dirname
        i = p.rfind('/') + 1
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

JAVA_HOME value is `/etc/java-8-openjdk`

Comment: There's an issue in `pyinstaller`'s GH about the same, it might help: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1839

Comment: you can also use conda :  `conda install -c ijstokes pydoop=1.2.0 `...

Comment: not same problem, but thanks :)

Comment: @Dadep: i get this now when run conda: UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pydoop 1.2.0* -> python 3.5*
  - python 2.7*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

Comment: Where is `JAVA_HOME` value set? What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` return?

Comment: @franklinsijo: JAVA_HOME value is set in /etc/profile, and echo $JAVA_HOME is /etc/java-8-openjdk

Comment: As you see the error that I've got the same, you should install the 3.5 or upper version of python `conda install python=3.5`

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error when trying to install pydoop package on an HDP node, CentOS7.

I manually set JAVA_HOME to the path below before I ran pip install.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin
```

More details:
Here is the error when the package is installed to Python 2.7

```
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 129, in dirname
        i = p.rfind('/') + 1
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Here is the error when the package is installed to 3.6

```
 File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 156, in dirname
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Later on, I found out that I had two mistakes.
1. the JAVA SDK was not was not installed.
2. the JAVA_HOME was correct. After SDK is installed, the JAVA_HOME should be

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64
```

After that, I am able to install pydoop successfully.